# react native flow error when using FlatList

Tags: react-native, flowtype

Flow version : '0.53.1'
react native version : 0.47.2

FlatList Code:

```
<FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      data={this.state.videoList}
      renderItem={this._renderRow}
      numColumns={2}
      horizontal={false}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      onEndReachedThreshold={5}
      onEndReached={() => {}}
    />
```

Other related codes :

```
type State = {
  videoList: Array<VideoItem>,
};

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videoList: [],
    };
  }
```

The error is :

> file:
>   'file:///Users/rockvr/Documents/VRPlayer/react-native/js/recommend/RecommendMoreVideo.js'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'exact type: object type (This type is
>   incompatible with union: undefined | null | boolean | number | string
>   | type application of type `React$Element` | type application of
>   identifier `Iterable` See also: React element `FlatList` Member 1:
>   Error: inconsistent use of library definitions object type This type
>   is incompatible with Member 2: Error: inconsistent use of library
>   definitions object type This type is incompatible with Member 3:
>   boolean Error: inconsistent use of library definitions object type
>   This type is incompatible with boolean Member 4: number Error:
>   inconsistent use of library definitions object type This type is
>   incompatible with number Member 5: string Error: inconsistent use of
>   library definitions object type This type is incompatible with string
>   Member 6: type application of type `React$Element` Error: type
>   application of property `PureComponent` Too many type arguments.
>   Expected at most 2 See type parameters of definition here Member 7:
>   type application of identifier `Iterable` Error: inconsistent use of
>   library definitions property `@@iterator` of $Iterable Property not
>   found in object type)' at: '41,9' source: 'flow'

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?